# How to bulk share / invite a site collection to multiple external customers using Powershell?

Tags: office-365

I have a number of users who are on an O365 SharePoint site that we manage that need access to another O365 SharePoint site. Both are separate Tenants.

Rather than email them individually I want to bulk send them an invite, how can I do this?

At the same time I want to catch those invites (which can be done using a mail flow rule to send the invitation email to another email address) but need to also accept them automatically in bulk.

How best can I do this with PowerShell?

Thank you in advance.